How to process stream data on Nuxt server
I'm trying to figure out the best way to process stream data on a Nuxt server.
On the frontend, I'm reading in a file, splitting it up into chunks, and sending it to the backend. However, I'm not sure how to handle the stream data on the server side. Does anyone have any ideas?
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="file"
      @input="onUpload"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const onUpload = ({files: File[]}): void => {
  const uploadFile = files.at(0);
  console.log('upload file', uploadFile);

  if (!uploadFile) return;

  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(uploadFile);

  fileReader.onload = async (event) => {
    if (!event?.target?.result) return;
    // file content
    const content = event.target.result;
    // fix chunk size
    const CHUNK_SIZE = 5000;
    // total chunks
    const totalChunks = event.target.result.byteLength / CHUNK_SIZE;

    // loop over each chunk
    for (let chunk = 0; chunk < totalChunks + 1; chunk++) {
      // prepare the chunk
      let CHUNK = content.slice(
        chunk * CHUNK_SIZE,
        (chunk + 1) * CHUNK_SIZE
      ) as 

      await $fetch('/api/upload', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
          contentLength: CHUNK.byteLength.toString(),
        },
        body: CHUNK,
      });
    }
    console.log('Complete File read successfully!');
  };
};
</script>

